# XmlDocument Agregar un registro

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Estoy trabajando con `XmlDocument` lo estoy usando como base de datos porque solo voy a agregar tres registros a lo mucho, necesito hacer un CRUD.

Tengo un registro pero tengo la necesidad de agregarle mas registros al xml tengo el siguiente código.

```
public void Create(Configuracion entity)
    {
        var destinoRutaArchivo = string.Concat(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
            @"\ConfiguracionFE");
        var destinoFile = Path.Combine(destinoRutaArchivo, "Configuracion.xml");
        if (!Directory.Exists(destinoRutaArchivo)) { Directory.CreateDirectory(destinoRutaArchivo); }

        XDocument configuracionXml = new XDocument(
            new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
            new XComment("Configuracion"),
            new XElement("DocumentElement",
                new XElement("Configuracion",
                    new XElement("ConfiguracionId", entity.ConfiguracionId),
                    new XElement("Ruc", entity.Ruc),
                    new XElement("RazonSocial", entity.RazonSocial),
                    new XElement("RutaXmlGenerado", entity.RutaXmlGenerado),
                    new XElement("RutaXmlAutorizado", entity.RutaXmlAutorizado),
                    new XElement("RutaFirma", entity.RutaFirma),
                    new XElement("Clave", entity.Clave),
                    new XElement("Ambiente", entity.Ambiente))
                ));
        if (File.Exists(destinoFile))
        {
            var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(destinoFile);
            //Agregar nuevo registro
        }
        else
        {
            configuracionXml.Save(destinoFile);
        }
    }
```

Este es el xml que me da.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!--Configuracion-->
<DocumentElement>
    <Configuracion>
        <ConfiguracionId>0</ConfiguracionId>
        <Ruc>3333445666666</Ruc>
        <RazonSocial>QQQQQQQQQQQQQ</RazonSocial>
        <RutaXmlGenerado>C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\ecuador\ejemplos\csharp</RutaXmlGenerado>
        <RutaXmlAutorizado>C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\ecuador\xades</RutaXmlAutorizado>
        <RutaFirma>C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\Firma\xxxxxxxxxxxx.p12</RutaFirma>
        <Clave>werfs34</Clave>
        <Ambiente>Prueba</Ambiente>
    </Configuracion>
</DocumentElement>
```

Necesito agregarle mas registro como verán le debo de agregar más registro como si fuera una base de datos, se que para agregarle mas registro debo cargar primero el xml pero no se como agregarle un nuevo registro.

Comment: Hola yo estoy tratando de hacer lo mismo y sé cómo se hace para agregar más items pero lo tengo de forma manual. Lo que tienes que hacer es crear una clase y dentro tener el nombre de los campos que quieres llenar para que sean mostrados en tu xml, como te dije lo tengo de forma manual, puedo generar 3 items y llenar sus campos y me los muestra en el xml. quizas te sirva como ayuda revisa mi pregunta y si me puedes ayudar tu te lo agradecería. [Pregunta Stackoverflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/241811/problema-para-generar-un-xml-con-una-lista?noredirect=1#comment449593_241811) Sal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si vas a usas un `xml` como base de datos porque no usas la `serializacion` de una lista en base a una clase que definas, es mucho mas simple de obtener pocos datos y persistirlo, en lugar de tener que parsear cada nodo

[Cómo serializar un objeto](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/serialization/how-to-serialize-an-object)

[Cómo deserializar un objeto](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/serialization/how-to-deserialize-an-object)

Entonces con crear una instancia nueva en una lista en base a la clase que mapea con el xml puedes recuperar y persistir nuevos items usando c# directamente

```
List<Configuracion> config = new List<Configuracion>();  

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Configuracion>));  

StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(destinoFile);  
serializer.Serialize(writer, config);  
writer.Close();
```

En este caso la clase que defini es `Configuracion` y tendra las propiedades de cada nodo de informacion que necesites

[Convert XML and JSON to C# Classes](https://dennymichael.net/2014/05/30/convert-xml-to-csharp-classes/comment-page-1/)

Puedes obtenr la clas en base al xml

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]