# Problema para generar un xml con una lista

Tags: c#, xml

Estoy partiendo con lo que es la programación en c# y me pidieron generar un documento xml. Dejo una parte del código del documento con su estructura:

```
//documento creado en C# para la creacion de un documento xml
            XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(
                new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
                new XElement("Documento",
                    new XAttribute("id", "000001"),

                    new XElement("Signers",
                        new XElement("Signer",
                            new XAttribute("Type", "Rut")
                        )
                   ),

                    new XElement("Content",
                        new XElement("sve",
                            new XElement("Documento",
                                new XAttribute("ID", "Documento101"),
                                new XAttribute("xmlns", ""),
                                new XComment("Lo que es la cabecera del documento"),
                                from Cabecera in Cabecera.GetCabecera()
                                select new XElement("cabecera",
                                       new XElement("garantia_numero", Cabecera.nUsuarioRutNumero[0]),
                                       new XElement("informacion_adicional", Cabecera.InformacionAdicional),
                                       new XElement("procedencia_codigo", Cabecera.ProcedenciaCodigo),
                                        new XElement("numero_provisorio", Cabecera.NumeroProvisorio),
                                        new XElement("numero_interno_usuario", Cabecera.NumeroInternoUsuario),
                                        new XElement("pais_codigo", Cabecera.PaisCodigo),
                                        new XElement("glosa", Cabecera.Glosa),
                                        new XElement("usuario_rut_numero", Cabecera.UsuarioRutNumero),
                                        new XElement("usuario_rut_dv", Cabecera.UsuarioRutDv),
                                        new XElement("puerto_embarque_codigo", Cabecera.PuertoEmbarqueCodigo),
                                        new XElement("tipo_tramite_codigo", Cabecera.TipoTramiteCodigo),
                                        new XElement("ubicacion_destino_codigo", Cabecera.UbicacionDestinoCodigo),
                                        new XElement("moneda_codigo", Cabecera.MonedaCodigo),
                                        new XElement("medio_transporte_codigo", Cabecera.MedioTransporteCodigo),
                                        new XElement("pais_origen", Cabecera.PaisOrigen),
                                        new XElement("valor_fob", Cabecera.ValorFob),
                                        new XElement("valor_flete", Cabecera.ValorFlete),
                                        new XElement("valor_seguro", Cabecera.ValorSeguro),
                                        new XElement("valor_cif", Cabecera.ValorCif),
                                        new XElement("clausula", Cabecera.Clausula),
                                        new XElement("transbordo_nacional", Cabecera.TransbordoNacional),
                                        new XElement("transbordo_extranjero", Cabecera.TransbordoExtranjero)
                                ),
```

El `from Cabecera in Cabecera.GetCabecera()` llama a mi clase Cabecera.cs en donde tengo el código en donde creo los atributos de la cabecera y genero esta lista, este es el código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{

    public class Cabecera
    {

        // se definen los tipos y las variables para la cabecera
        public int GarantiaNumero { get; set; }
        public string InformacionAdicional { get; set; }
        public string ProcedenciaCodigo { get; set; }
        public int NumeroProvisorio { get; set; }
        public int NumeroInternoUsuario { get; set; }
        public int PaisCodigo { get; set; }
        public string Glosa { get; set; }
        public int UsuarioRutNumero { get; set; }
        public int UsuarioRutDv { get; set; }
        public int PuertoEmbarqueCodigo { get; set; }
        public string TipoTramiteCodigo { get; set; }
        public string UbicacionDestinoCodigo { get; set; }
        public int MonedaCodigo { get; set; }
        public int MedioTransporteCodigo { get; set; }
        public int PaisOrigen { get; set; }
        public float ValorFob { get; set; }
        public float ValorFlete { get; set; }
        public float ValorSeguro { get; set; }
        public float ValorCif { get; set; }
        public string Clausula { get; set; }
        public string TransbordoNacional { get; set; }
        public string TransbordoExtranjero { get; set; }

        public static List<Cabecera> GetCabecera()
        {
            List<Cabecera> ListaCabecera = new List<Cabecera>()
            {

             new Cabecera{GarantiaNumero=1,
                 InformacionAdicional = "lalal",
                 ProcedenciaCodigo ="0001",
                 NumeroProvisorio =010101,
                 PaisCodigo =001,
                 Glosa = "tessto",
                 UsuarioRutNumero = 16163632,
                 UsuarioRutDv = 6,
                 PuertoEmbarqueCodigo = 09,
                 TipoTramiteCodigo = "lala",
                 UbicacionDestinoCodigo = "chile",
                 MonedaCodigo = 01,
                 MedioTransporteCodigo = 01,
                 PaisOrigen = 01,
                 ValorFob = 4.5f ,
                ValorFlete = 7.1f, ValorSeguro = 40.4f, ValorCif = 5.5f, Clausula = "clausura",
                 TransbordoNacional = "ciudad 1", TransbordoExtranjero = "ciudad 2"}

            };

            return ListaCabecera;
        }
```

Creo la lista cabecera

`List<Cabecera> ListaCabecera = new List<Cabecera>()`

y creo un item en donde yo le tengo que pasar los datos manualmente, si quiero crear otra cabecera, tengo que crear otra **new Cabecera** y volver a llenar.

El caso es que para crear una o dos cabeceras no tengo problema porque son pocas las lineas que tengo que escribir y así como está genero bien el .xml.

Pero me pusieron el problema de que sea capaz de llamar estos datos para una cabecera que están guardados en una base de datos, sé cómo realizar la consulta sql pero ahora mi duda es:

**Tengo que generar otra forma para guardar los datos que traiga de la consulta sql?** Quizás con un arraylist por lo que estuve leyendo.

Se me ocurrió lo siguiente:

```
public static List<int> inGarantiaNumero = new List<int>();
public static List<string> inInformacionAdicional = new List<string>();
public static List<string> inProcedenciaCodigo = new List<string>();
```

Así generaría las listas para cada una de las características. y de la misma forma todas las características en la posición 0 corresponderían con la primera cabecera, las que estén en la posición 1 serían de la segunda cabecera y así. En base a esta lógica se me ocurrió escribir esto pero creo que no me va a servir ya que visual studio me alega varios errores.

```
public static List<Cabecera> GetCabecera()
        {
            List<Cabecera> ListaCabecera = new List<Cabecera>()
            {
                for(int i =0; i<= GarantiaNumero.Count; i++)
                {
                new Cabecera { nGarantiaNumero = inGarantiaNumero[i], nInformacionAdicional = inInformacionAdicional[i], ... }
                }
            };

            return ListaCabecera;
        }
```

Quería saber si alguno de ustedes sabe como implementar esto o si me puede dar otro ejemplo de lista en donde pueda implementar un ciclo for u otra cosa.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta

Comment: ¿Cual es la intención de llevar esa información a un archivo xml si ya lo tienes en una tabla trabajala desde ahí?

Comment: el motivo es que al cliente, que va a tener esta aplicación, después por otra parte, otro ente, les pide esta información en este formato como un documento xml firmado. Entonces necesitamos poder pasar esta información de una base de datos y generar un archivo xml

Comment: Puedo darte una respuesta a esto, pero me parece que es claramente como lo que te dije en la otra pregunta un problema XY. Tu codigo es confuso, y tu idea es mas confusa. Que es cabecera? como es la estructura de tu xml? esta perfecto que muestres todo lo que intentaste (no lo saques!) pero veamos en perspectiva que necesitas hacer. Si lo que tenes que hacer es un xml que tenga un tag cabecera y muchos hijos, en realidad "podrias" tener un objeto cabecera, y dentro de el los datos de los hijos. La lista de cabeceras esta bien, pero no dentro de la clase cabeceras!

Comment: La clase cabecera solo tiene los datos de las cabeceras y los datos de su contenido (los hijos, tal vez esos si sean listas). Y despues en algun lado tendras una lista de cabeceras. Cuando vos traes todo de la db, "podrias" (no parece necesario) bajar todo eso a clases, y despues construir el xml. pero ya solo recorriendo las cabeceras y que cada clase tenga un metodo armar xml que sepa que xml devolver segun los datos que tiene.

Comment: me puedes dar un ejemplo? ya me marié un poco con tanta información

Comment: Ya pude hacer lo que necesitaba, y funciona de maravilla, sirve que ponga la respuesta para otras personas que quizás estén buscando lo mismo?